# How to make LESS data-uri function fail if file does not exist?

Tags: gruntjs, less, data-uri

I'm using Grunt to build my web client and my LESS files include calls to the data-uri function in order to embed images in the resulting CSS file.
Sometimes a developer makes a mistake (like a typo or bad copy-paste) in the passed file name and **the result is url('...')**. This refers to a path in the production server which does not exist.

Example: the developer wrote data-uri('path/abc.png') but the filename is "abc.PNG". The result in the CSS is url('path/abc.png').

**In these cases, I want data-uri to simply throw an error and break the build, preferably with an appropriate message. Is there a way to do this?**

I've looked for a flag or some configuration to enable this, something like "nonull" which is available in some modules, no luck finding one.

Using Grunt 0.4.5, grunt-contrib-less 1.0.1. My next step is to try to update to ...-less 1.1.0 but nothing in the docs suggests it might change anything.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything with this by now. The compiler actually generates a warning when file does not exist, but (AFAIR) `grunt-contrib-less` (neither any other Less compiler wrapper) does not currently support the warnings facility.

Comment: Would love to get a "second opinion" on seven's comment. :) 
But maybe there IS an answer from different direction? A pre-less task to validate contents of data-uris? A post-less task to check if there are unwanted url('...')? 
Whatever might work.

Comment: Well, if it's really important you can simply patch the compiler source code to generate error instead of warning (or in less intrusive way write a compiler plugin that does this).